# Copy table + new PK

Tags: primary-key

I have a table without a PK.
The table has about 500 rows so I don't want to write them manually.
What's the best way to add a PK?

Thank you,

Rafa

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD PkColumn INT NOT NULL IDENTITY
ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT PK_T PRIMARY KEY (PkColumn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. simple program which reads all records and inserts them to new table with PK?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE CurrentTable ADD pkNewColumn INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE CurrentTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_pkNewColumn PRIMARY KEY (pkNewColumn)
```

Comment: Why truncate the table and reinsert the rows?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if your adding a new column that will be a primary key or if you want to designate an existing column as a primary key.  To modify an existing column:

Create a clone of your current table, and backup the 500 rows using a

INSERT INTO BACKUP_TABLE ( COLA, COLB, COLC ) SELECT COLA, COLB,COLC FROM TABLE;

Then recreate your original table with the primary key, and copy the backup table into the original using a similary SQL statement as above.